# Multiple div with the same class and only one jquery for all of them

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with my jQuery code. I have multiple divs with the same class I generate this divs dynamically. The jQuery is very simple, just move the div top with an exact px number and show another div right under this one.

The problem is I cant figure out how to select the hovered one and don't move the other divs at the same time, just when I move the cursor on the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("h1").hide();
    $(".pin-holder").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".img-frame").animate({bottom: '80px'});
  $(".hidden-title").slideToggle();
   $("h1").fadeIn(600);
    });
  $(".pin-holder").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".img-frame").animate({bottom: '-0px'});
  $(".hidden-title").slideToggle();
  $("h1").fadeOut(600);

       });
    });
```

```css
.pin-holder{
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-left:95px;
     margin-top:50px;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
     overflow:hidden;/*+opció*/
}
.img-frame{
     display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
}
.hidden-title{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     width:100%;
     height:80px;
     background-color:red;
     display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pin-holder'>
    <div class='img-frame'><a href='#'><img src='pins/pic01.png' height='300' width='300'/></a></div>
        <div class='hidden-title'><h1>PLEASE WORK!</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class='pin-holder'>
        <div class='img-frame' id='frame01'><a href='#'><img src='pins/pic02.png' height='300' width='300'/></div>
        <div class='hidden-title'><h1>PLEASE WORK!</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `this` as the context of your selectors in the event handler: `$("...", this)`

Answer (score 1):

Is it this behaviour you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("h1").hide();
    $(".pin-holder").mouseenter(function(){
    debugger;
    $(this).animate({bottom: '80px'});
  $(this).find(".hidden-title").slideToggle();
   $(this).find("h1").fadeIn(600);
    $(this).find('img').hide()
    });
  $(".pin-holder").mouseleave(function(){
   debugger;
   $(this).find('img').show()
        $(this).animate({bottom: '-0px'});
  $(this).find(".hidden-title").slideToggle();
  $(this).find("h1").fadeOut(600);

       });
    });
```

```css
.pin-holder{
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-left:95px;
     margin-top:50px;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
     overflow:hidden;/*+opció*/
}
.img-frame{
     display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
}
.hidden-title{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     width:100%;
     height:80px;
     background-color:red;
     display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pin-holder'>
    <div class='img-frame'><a href='#'><img src='pins/pic01.png' height='300' width='300'/></a></div>
        <div class='hidden-title'><h1>PLEASE WORK!</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class='pin-holder'>
        <div class='img-frame' id='frame01'><a href='#'><img src='pins/pic02.png' height='300' width='300'/></div>
        <div class='hidden-title'><h1>PLEASE WORK!</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GeorgeMarchello please see the updated code in the snippet. Is this what you desire?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you do not need jquery. Instead, you can do this by transition. You can do this only by  a few lines of css. Add this styles:

```css
.img-frame, .hidden-title, h1{
        transition-duration: 1s;
    }
    
    .pin-holder:hover .hidden-title { bottom: 0; }
    .pin-holder:hover h1{ display: block;}
    .pin-holder{
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-left:95px;
     margin-top:50px;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
     overflow:hidden;/*+opció*/
}
.img-frame{
     display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
}
.hidden-title{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     width:100%;
     height:80px;
     background-color:red;     
     bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='pin-holder'>
    <div class='img-frame'><a href='#'><img src='pins/pic01.png' height='300' width='300'/></a></div>
        <div class='hidden-title'><h1>PLEASE WORK!</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class='pin-holder'>
        <div class='img-frame' id='frame01'><a href='#'><img src='pins/pic02.png' height='300' width='300'/></div>
        <div class='hidden-title'><h1>PLEASE WORK!</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this` selector to get hovered element. (use it inside event functions)

```
$(this).find(/*element you want to select here*/)
```